# So should SO be set to read only?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, april-fools

Now that we have reached the point where we have the answers to every question that could ever be asked, I was thinking it was probably time we set SO to read only.

Since there will never been any new content it will be much easer for us to support it this way.

Comment: You should tag this `aprils-fools`.

Comment: Folks, take note of today's date ;)

Comment: see now I didn't know we had an april fools tag.   Don't think we didn't last year how very taggie of you.

Comment: Did I just use a status-tag next to a baited title that might totally scare the socks off of everyone that notices it? Why yes, yes I did.

Comment: @TimPost Touché !

Comment: @TimPost  you need to lock this post now, so that people will freak out when they try to comment or vote and find that it's... READ ONLY

Answer (score 8):

I TOTALLY [FELL FOR THIS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277775/revisions).

Bravo.

Comment: I wonder how large SO database is now that it contains every question.

Comment: THIS IS MY FAVOURITE ANSWER ON SE

Answer (score 3):

[You should really use jQuery for that!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/245360)

---

Bravo. You got us in this one!

Comment: -1 not enough jquery.

Comment: Yeah good point I was thinking we need to work on this search algorithm as well.   I have been trying to find out how windows 10 suddenly has a Linux kernel.  Haven't had any luck finding it yet, must be here some where.

Comment: @tim how could I disagree. Please let me downvote my own answer.